# Is it possible to make a maven-repository with a static-website?

Tags: maven

Stupide idea but ... is it possible to create a maven repository from a static website?

if I mannualy put pom and jar file on a website with a path similar to the one on any maven repository, then I reference the website as a maven repository from which I try to import dependency,  will it work ?

I need it in order to store my snapshot version without publishing them. I don't care of security but I have 0 budget

Comment: Rather than re-invent wheels, there are services that offer free Maven hosting for individuals. This looks like one of them: https://packagecloud.io/l/maven-repository
No, I'm not associated, so I can't tell you more.

Comment: There is central https://central.sonatype.org/ there is GitHub: https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages there is GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/

Comment: The issue with github package is that it don't allow to rewrite your package. So it don't work on snapshot versions

Comment: If you don't work with SNAPSHOT's then you are working on releases. That means each change produces a new version so I don't see the issue?

Comment: The issue is that I work on snapshot version